# List to numpy array conversion possible bug

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Recently, I've faced the problem with `np.array(list)` conversion. Assume we have a list of 3 numpy 2D arrays with shapes `(x, y), (x, y), (x, z)` so that `shape[0]` is the same for all arrays in the list. In that case, conversion to array fails with

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape **(x, z)** into
>   shape **(x)**

Numpy tries to create and array of shape `(3, x, y)` instead of leaving it list-like structure (array of different arrays).
If at least one `shape[0]` differs from the other, we get what we want, array of arrays with shape `(3,)`

I overcame that problem by adding an element of different type to list, and using `np.array(list)[:-1]`. So, is it a bug, or I missed something (like np.array() params, etc.)?

Some examples:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.ones((3,2))
>>> y = np.ones((3,2))
>>> z = np.ones((3,3))
>>> a = np.ones((2,3))
>>> xyz = np.array([x,y,z])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,2) into shape (3)
>>> xza = np.array([x,z,a])
[array([[ 1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.]]) 
 array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
 array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])]
>>> xyz2 = np.array([x,y,z,'tmp'])[:-1]
[array([[ 1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.]])
 array([[ 1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.]])
 array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])]
```

Answer (score 1):

On version 1.9 I get different results (error)

3 same shape arrays produce the expected 3d array:

```
In [726]: np.array([np.ones((3,2)),np.ones((3,2)),np.ones((3,2))]).shape
Out[726]: (3, 3, 2)
```

but if one differs in columns, I get 3x3 object array filled with None:

```
In [727]: np.array([np.ones((3,2)),np.ones((3,2)),np.ones((3,3))])
Out[727]: 
array([[None, None, None],
       [None, None, None],
       [None, None, None]], dtype=object)
```

What's your version?  More evidence of an area under development.  This test rings a bell - I think I've seen a SO question like this before.  But I'm not sure how search for it.

Matching github issue:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6591

and from your comment:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7103

which references a recent SO question (which I must have looked at):

[ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 5 to array axis with dimension 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948867/valueerror-cannot-copy-sequence-with-size-5-to-array-axis-with-dimension-2)

---

As you say, if the first dimension differs it creates the object array.

Most commonly I've seen it with 1d arrays or lists, e.g.

```
In [711]: np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[4,5,6]])
Out[711]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [4, 5, 6]])

In [712]: np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[4,5]])
Out[712]: array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5]], dtype=object)
```

I've also recommended creating a `np.array((3,),dtype=object)` array, and filling that.

Looks like it is testing the first dimension for uniformity, and starts to fill it in.  Your error suggests it is trying to do some broadcasting, though I can't think of an example where that works.

We could examine the numpy Github issues. There probably are a variety of ones related to object arrays.  This is something of a late comer kludge, expanding numpy arrays beyond the original uniform multidimensional concept.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My numpy version is 1.10.1. Seems, that they noticed the error, so now it throws ValueError instead array of 'None's. I explored GitHub issues, and found that [issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7103). Not exactly the same problem, but it stems from the same place i suppose. May be implementing full shape (not only 1st dimension) check will help.