# pandas.Panel(data=list_of_dfs) broken?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, panel

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

print(np.__version__)
print(pd.__version__)

d1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],'number': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]})
d2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'number': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}) 

x=[d1,d2]
pd.Panel(x, items=[1,2])
```

Error:

```
<python dir>\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    472 
    473     """
--> 474     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    475 
    476 def asanyarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):

ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 5 to array axis with dimension 2
```

I think it is related to the following post, but I'm not sure what the best workaround is: [ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 5 to array axis with dimension 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948867/valueerror-cannot-copy-sequence-with-size-5-to-array-axis-with-dimension-2)

Comment: An obvious workaround is to create a dict and pass in the dict of DFs instead of a list, but given that it's a standard initiator of the Panel class to take a list of DataFrames, it appears weird that it should not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the doc, the Panel constructor only takes ndarray or dict of DataFrame. You may want to convert the list of DataFrame into dict first.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

print(np.__version__)
print(pd.__version__)

d1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],'number': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]})
d2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'number': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]})

x = dict(enumerate([d1,d2], 1))
pd.Panel(x)
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.html#pandas.Panel

Comment: Ha. Good disclaimer that it only takes an ndarray. Sneaky sneaky. Reading through their code though, it checks the type of the input to see if it's an instance of (list, ndarray), so apparently the "intention" was to support both arrays and lists of DataFrames. I do think this is something that the Pandas team should try to fix.