# Data structure for KMeans clustering using Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, numpy, sklearn-pandas

I am currently working on some scientific data and I am trying to perform a clustering task on it but I get a Value error due to the the format of the data. Which is two Pandas DataFrames in [170 rows x 7 columns].

I have tried transposing the data, formatting as a list, and also a numpy array. The format I am showing in the code is from a solution found here: [ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 5 to array axis with dimension 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948867/valueerror-cannot-copy-sequence-with-size-5-to-array-axis-with-dimension-2)

```
#x is the y distance
x = np.empty(7, dtype = object)
x[:] = [distance_lC, distance_fC]

#y is the speed.
y = np.empty(7, dtype = object)
y[:] = [speed_lC, speed_fC]

cell_kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 4).fit_predict(y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.scatterplot(cell_kmeans)
plt.show()
```

The output should give out the cluster. But I have the following Value Error: "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence."

Comment: I think that when you do `y[:] = [speed_lC, speed_fC]` your `y` will become a list and scikit won't like it! could you tell us what `speed_lC, speed_fC` are? (use `type(speed_lC)`)

Comment: Hi! Yeah as stated the two variables I'm using are pandas DataFrames. So using `type` outputs: `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concatenate the dataframes instead:

```
y = pandas.concat([speed_lC, speed_fC])
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried using pd.concat before but didn't use the regular brackets... That works just fine now. So using numpy is not good when having these DataFrames sizes!