# Python, Keras, RNN: cannot copy sequence with size 7 to array axis with dimension 5

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras, recurrent-neural-network

When I Run this code:

```
model = Sequential([
    LSTM(300, activation='tanh', input_shape=data.shape, recurrent_activation='sigmoid'),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Dense(4, activation='linear')
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
history = model.fit_generator(training, epochs=22, steps_per_epoch=1)
```

This error pops up:
`ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 7 to array axis with dimension 5`
I don't know how to handle that. Yesterday, the code worked perfectly. In other threads I've found; the error might be related to `np.vstack`. [This is the thread I'm writing about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948867/valueerror-cannot-copy-sequence-with-size-5-to-array-axis-with-dimension-2).

I've tried to change the data to a `np.array` but it did not work. Can anyone help?

This might be useful:
`training = TimeseriesGenerator(data, data, length=7, batch_size=6)`

`TimeseriesGenerator` is from `keras.preprocessing.sequence`

Answer (score 0):

You need input numpy arrays into Keras' TimeSeries generator, not directly DataFrames, you can do data.values for pass numpy only.